# HttpNotFoundException message not displayed in Laravel

Tags: laravel, exception

I am handling the HttpNotFoundException and want to when redirecting back with an error message, but it does not display the error message?
can anybody help me with it?
this is my Handler class render method

```
public function render($request, Throwable $e)
{
    if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException){
        return back()->withErrors(['message' => 'any message']);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

and my login page

```
@if (Session::has('message'))
                            <h1>{{ Session::get('message') }}</h1>
                        @endif
                        @error('message')
                            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"
                                    style="text-align: left;">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                                </button>
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </div>
                        @enderror
```

Comment: you must be use `@if($errors->any()) <ul class="alert alert-danger px-3"> @foreach($errors->all() as $error) <li>{{ $error }}</li> @endforeach </ul> @endif`

Comment: if tou want use `Session::get('message')` inside exception use `->with(['key' => 'value'])`.

Comment: if you are using `Lumen` then you need be add `Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession` in the middleware (bootstrap/app.php)

Comment: still not working in both ways, don't know what to do

Comment: are you getting an error? or is your session empty?

Comment: if your session empty then check `Illuminate\Support\MessageBag` and `Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag`

Comment: it display the message in MessageBag's constructor but not displaying in view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution in [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/session-variables-inside-exceptionhandler).

just added `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` to middleware array of kernel.php

Thanks from all.

Comment: I told you this solution in the third comment :|

Comment: sorry, I forget, thanks again @kooroshsafeashrafi